# Python 3 Beautifulsoup to scrape county names from a gov.uk webpage

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

I would be grateful for any help!

I'm trying to scrape the county names on this webpage (https://www.gov.uk/guidance/full-list-of-local-restriction-tiers-by-area) into four corresponding lists: Tier1, Tier2, Tier3, Tier4.

The issue is how I'm navigating the page...
This is how I'm setting my soup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.gov.uk/guidance/full-list-of-local-restriction-tiers-by-area"
headers = {...}
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
```

I've tried finding the h2s and then looping through the siblings, find_all_next, etc. but I haven't had any luck.

**Endstate**
I'm trying to put each of the counties into a CSV that looks like this:
(colour is mapped as follows Tier 1:green, Tier 2:yellow, Tier 3:amber, Tier 4:red)

| County | Country | Tier | colour |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Isles of Scilly | England | 1 | Green |
| Rutland | England | 3 | Amber |
| etc. |  |  |  |

**Update**: As a bare minimum example of the data to be extracted:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''<div class="govspeak">
<ul>
  <li>case detection rates in all age groups</li>
</ul>
<h2 id="tier-1-medium-alert">Tier 1: Medium alert</h2>
<h3 id="south-west">South West</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Isles of Scilly</li>
</ul>
<h2 id="tier-2-high-alert">Tier 2: High alert</h2>
<p>No areas are currently in Tier 2.</p>
<h2 id="tier-3-very-high-alert">Tier 3: Very High alert</h2>
<h3 id="east-midlands">East Midlands</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Rutland</li>
</ul>
<h3 id="north-west">North West</h3>
<ul>
  <li>Liverpool City Region</li>
</ul>
</div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
h2 = soup.find_all('h2')
# Whats the best way to find related li tags?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that the HTML is the `H2` & `UL` are in a flat structure. There are many ways to extract the data. For example preforming `For` loop on every element.

- `soup.find('div', {"class": "govspeak"})` - Find the parent div (that contains `h2` & `li`).
- `container.find_all('li')` - Find all the `li`.
- `x.fetchPrevious('h2')[0].text.strip()` - Find the first `[0]` previous `h2` (and remove any whitespaces).
- `if x.fetchPrevious('h2')[0].findParent('div', {"class": "govspeak"})` - filter out any `h2` that don't appear inside the parent div. (as `fetchPrevious` will literally find the previous).
- `namedtuple` (which I've called `CountyTierModel`) to store the scraped data as an array.
- `re.search("(?<=Tier )\d(?=:)", x.tier)` - `RegEx` to fetch number from `h2` title.

**Example for scraping data:**

```
from collections import namedtuple
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
CountyTierModel = namedtuple('CountyTiers', ['tier', 'county'])

url = "https://www.gov.uk/guidance/full-list-of-local-restriction-tiers-by-area"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "lxml")
container = soup.find('div', {"class": "govspeak"})
results = [CountyTierModel(x.fetchPrevious('h2')[0].text.strip(), x.text.strip()) for x in container.find_all('li') 
                if x.fetchPrevious('h2') and x.fetchPrevious('h2')[0].findParent('div', {"class": "govspeak"})]

# Here you can write yor code to convert to CSV & provide mapping for Country & Color.
for x in results:
    # Regex to extract number from H2 title based on starting with 'Tier ' + number + ':'
    m = re.search("(?<=Tier )\d(?=:)", x.tier)
    print(f"{m.group(0)} - {x.county}")
```

**Output:**

```
1 - Isles of Scilly
3 - Rutland
3 - Liverpool City Region
3 - Bath and North East Somerset
3 - Bristol
3 - Cornwall
3 - Devon, Plymouth and Torbay
3 - Dorset
3 - North Somerset
3 - South Gloucestershire
3 - Wiltshire
3 - Herefordshire
3 - Shropshire, and Telford and Wrekin
3 - Worcestershire
3 - City of York and North Yorkshire
3 - The Humber: East Riding of Yorkshire, Kingston upon Hull/Hull, North East Lincolnshire and North Lincolnshire
3 - South Yorkshire (Barnsley, Doncaster, Rotheram, Sheffield)
3 - West Yorkshire (Bradford, Calderdale, Kirklees, Leeds, Wakefield)
4 - Derby and Derbyshire
4 - Leicester City and Leicestershire
4 - Lincolnshire
4 - Northamptonshire
4 - Nottingham and Nottinghamshire
4 - Bedford, Central Bedfordshire, Luton and Milton Keynes
4 - Cambridgeshire
4 - Essex, Southend-on-Sea and Thurrock
4 - Hertfordshire
4 - Norfolk
4 - Peterborough
4 - Suffolk
4 - All 32 London boroughs plus City of London
4 - North East Combined Authority (this area includes the local authorities of County Durham, Gateshead, South Tyneside and Sunderland)
4 - North of Tyne Combined Authority (this area includes the local authorities of Newcastle-upon-Tyne, North Tyneside and Northumberland)
4 - Tees Valley Combined Authority (this area includes the local authorities of Darlington, Hartlepool, Middlesbrough, Redcar and Cleveland, and Stockton-on-Tees)
4 - Cumbria
4 - Greater Manchester
4 - Lancashire, Blackburn with Darwen, and Blackpool
4 - Warrington and Cheshire Region
4 - Berkshire
4 - Brighton and Hove, East Sussex and West Sussex
4 - Buckinghamshire
4 - Hampshire, Southampton and Portsmouth
4 - Isle of Wight
4 - Kent and Medway
4 - Oxfordshire
4 - Surrey
4 - Bournemouth, Christchurch and Poole
4 - Gloucestershire (Cheltenham, Cotswold, Forest of Dean, Gloucester City, Stroud and Tewkesbury)
4 - Somerset (Mendip, Sedgemoor, Somerset West and Taunton, and South Somerset)
4 - Swindon
4 - Birmingham, Dudley, Sandwell, Walsall and Wolverhampton
4 - Coventry
4 - Solihull
4 - Staffordshire and Stoke-on-Trent
4 - Warwickshire
```

*Note: To keep the question focused; I've only added code for scraping. Extracting to CSV should be a separate question*.

Comment: Thanks Greg! Makes sense, much appreciated!